# propositions of Interior and closure

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,{\tau})$ a topological space, i have to show:

1. $A{\bigcup}B={X} \Rightarrow \text{cl } A{\bigcup}\text{int } B={X}$
2. $A{\bigcap}B=\varnothing \Rightarrow \text{cl }A{\bigcap}\text{int }B={\varnothing}$

Well, my proof of 2) is this:

$x\in (\text{cl }A{\bigcap}\text{int }B) {\Rightarrow}$  $x\in \text{cl }A$ and $x\in \text{int }B$

${\hspace{3.3cm}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $(\exists U\in \mathcal{N}(x),U\subset B)$ and $(\forall V\in \mathcal{N}(x), V{\bigcap}A \neq \varnothing)$

Here $\mathcal{N}(x)$ denote neighborhood system of $x$, so, $V{\bigcap}A {\subset} A$ and by hypotesis $A{\bigcap}B={\varnothing}$, i can conclude:

$(V{\bigcap}A){\bigcap} B\subset A{\bigcap}B \subset \varnothing$

Then $x\in\varnothing$. Conversely, it's always true.

For the 1) I have this part of the proof:

$x\in (\text{cl }A{\bigcup}\text{int }B) {\Rightarrow}$ $x\in \text{cl }A$ or $x\in \text{int }B$

${\hspace{3.3cm}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $(\exists U\in \mathcal{N}(x),U\subset B)$ or $(\forall V\in \mathcal{N}(x), V{\bigcap}A \neq \varnothing)$

(And this analysis is similar to the first proof) but I have trouble by the other hand. Can you give some advice or hint to do this? Do you think I'm right on my proofs? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$ $\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$Your proof of (2) starts off fine, but it goes a little astray at the end. (It would also be clearer if you used more words and fewer symbols.)

> Suppose that $x\cl A\cap\int B$. Then $x\in\cl A$, and $x\in\int B$. Since $x\in\int B$, there is a $U\in\mathcal{N}(x)$ such that $U\subseteq B$, where $\mathcal{N}(x)$ is the nbhd system at $x$, and since $x\in\cl A$, $V\cap A\ne\varnothing$ for each $V\in\mathcal{N}(x)$. In particular, then, $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$, so $$\varnothing\ne U\cap A\subseteq B\cap A=\varnothing\;,$$ which is absurd. It follows that there is no such $x$ and hence that $\cl A\cap\int B=\varnothing$.

For (1) it’s probably easiest to prove the contrapositive: show that if $\cl A\cup\int B\ne X$, then $A\cup B\ne X$. Suppose that $x\in X\setminus(\cl A\cup\int B)$. Then $x\in X\setminus\cl A$, so there is a $U\in\mathcal{N}(x)$ such that $U\cap A=\varnothing$. And $x\in X\setminus\int B$, so $x\notin\int B$, and therefore $U\nsubseteq B$. At this point the proof is almost finished; can you complete it from here?

Comment: So, there exist some $y\in U$ such that $y\in X$ and $y\notin A{\cup}B$ then $A{\cup}B {\nsubset}X$ therefore the contrapositive is true and the other is true. right?

Comment: @angieduque: Did you mean that $y\color{red}{\notin}A\cup B$?

Comment: M.Scott: Yes,i did. Then $A{\cup}B \neq  X$ therefore the contrapositive is true so the other is true.

Comment: @angieduque: Almost: $A\cup B$ **is** a subset of $X$, and in fact a proper subset. The point is that the contrapositive is true because $X\setminus(A\cup B)\ne\varnothing$, i.e., $A\cup B\ne X$ (or, if you prefer, $A\cup B\subsetneqq X$).